# Full Text Search in Keywords column

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Table images with keywoeds  :

```
 ___________________________________________________________________
 |id| name |Keywords
 | 1| pic1 |book;much;pile;sellout;library;bookstore;knowledges;.....
 | 2| pic2 |Library;Bookshelf;Book;Shelf;No People;In A Row;Indoors;.
 |.n| picN |...........
 |__|______|________________________________________________________
```

what is the best way to index this table with depends on KEYWORDS column?
How can i make full text search in Keywords column, with good performance?

Comment: Never store multipe values in a single column!! Change your table design and your problems go away

Comment: If you already have a separated list of keywords, you can just use `REGEXP` or maybe `LIKE`.  But, why are you storing your keywords in CSV form?  This generally makes your data hard to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best away is as follows;

```
id| Keywords (or keyword_id instead)
 1| book
 1| much
 1| pile
 1| sellout
 1| library
 1| bookstore
 1| knowledges
 2| Library
 2| Bookshelf
 2| Book
 2| Shelf
 2| No People
 2| In A Row
```

Then, when searching for an `id` or `keyword` you may take advantage of the full power of the database, including things like indexing.

Full text search, as the name implies, it mainly for searching in a large corpus of text for keywords, not for searching a list of only keywords.